# Nextjs default route problem with [lang] folder

Tags: redirect, next.js, internationalization, directory-structure, i18next

Before i move my `layout.tsx` and `page.tsx` files into `[lang]` folder it looked like this

[image]

Then i moved those two files into `[lang]` folder because i needed to take the locale params in my `page.tsx`. Everything worked fine except when i first run the website it doesnt redirect to `/en/bootcamps` as i configured here in page.tsx :

```
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";   const redirectToBootcamp = async () => {redirect(`en/bootcamps`);};export default async function Home({ params }: { params: { lang: string } }) { await redirectToBootcamp();return <main>{JSON.stringify(params)}</main>;}
```

it goes to `/` instead and gives me 404 error. How can i make it redirect where i want and still keep the layout and page files in [lang] folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier you had `app/page.tsx`. That means `/` route will work fine.

Then you moved that file to `app/[lang]/page.tsx`, which means `/[lang]` route will work. But `/` wont work anympre.

For `/` to work, you need either:

- `app/page.tsx` (just like you had earlier), or
- create a redirect from `/` to `/[lang]` in `next.config.ts`

```
async redirects() {
    return [
        {
            source: '/',
            destination: '/en',
        },
    ]
},
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/redirects

Comment: It worked perfectly fine, i didn't know this . Thanks for answering, big help.